# IIS didn't send static file reqest to aspnetcore

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a aspnetcore 3.1.10 website hosted on windows server 2019 and IIS v10.

It runs InProcess mode.

Static files (js or css) are processed by aspnetcore's StaticFileMiddleware.

Resently, IIS sometimes returned an empty content css or js with http status code 200, and there is no process log in StaticFileMiddleware.

Normally there is log "Sending file. Request path: '"/styles/css/main.css"'. Physical path: '"D:\IIS\XXXXX\wwwroot\styles\css\main.css"'"

I didn't find any errors in aspnetcore logs or event viewer.

Only I can do is restarting IIS to make this issue disappeared for a while, how do I find out what's wrong with my website.

Comment: Do you enable the ARR for your web application ?I suggest you could try to enable the fail request tracing to log some details FRT logs. Then you could check these logs to find out which module handle this request. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).

Comment: @BrandoZhang Hi, I didn't use ARR. The request status code is 200, it is not fail, time-taken is also short. I can't use these conditions (status code or time-taken) in tracing logs.

Comment: 200 also could track. Could you add it as 200, it will also log 200 request.

Comment: @BrandoZhang , thanks, I added it.